# Angular 2 Routing - How to implement for my structure

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In the interest of self-learning, and improving my programming skills, I'm building an app using .NET Core and Angular 2.

Based on what I've read thus far, I've structured my NG2 app as follows (I haven't included all files) ...

```
/wwwroot
  - index.html
  - /app
    - app.module.ts
    - app.component.ts
    - app.component.html
    - app.route.ts
    - main.ts
    - /Components
      - /Home
        - home.module.ts
        - home.component.ts
        - home.component.html
        - /Dashboard
          - dashboard.module.ts
          - dashboard.component.ts
          - dashboard.component.html
      - /Nav
        - nav.module.ts
        - nav.component.ts
        - nav.component.html
      - /Scheduler
        - scheduler.module.ts
        - scheduler.component.ts
        - scheduler.component.html
        - /Calendar
          - calendar.module.ts
          - calendar.component.ts
          - calendar.component.html
        - /Appointment
          - appointment.module.ts
          - appointment.component.ts
          - appointment.component.html
```

I've read that it is recommended each component/feature have their own module.  Is this the same for routes?  That is, should each component/feature have their own route file?

I've also searched high and low to find how to implement routing.  What I'm trying to achieve is to have the NAV component appear at the top of the page (with the selected option highlighted), and then the selected component (e.g. Home, Scheduler, etc) appear in the body.  The Scheduler component might also have a sub-menu/tab system that would allow me to load in the calendar first (as the default view), or any other component under the Scheduler component.

Can someone please explain how I might achieve this, or point me to a resource that would explain clearly what I need to do to get this to work?  I've looked at the Angular doco, and various other resources, but they all seem to implement routing in different ways, or they use very simplistic examples, none of which come close to what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much trial and error I ended up ditching everything I had done and started from scratch.  This time I created my Angular 2 app using Angular 2 CLI tool.  I then set up the routing by checking out examples from https://school.scotch.io/routing-angular-2-applications/ and https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html (thanks to commenter Max Karpovets)

Using the CLI tool it was a breeze to create the components necessary and have them compile correctly.  I only had to add the route and module files manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you organised your app doesn't follow the best practice. You don't have to create special modules for Calendar, Appointment ... Just attach these components to Scheduler module.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html to help you having a good idea on how to organise your app in a better structure and modularisation:

Comment: I see what you're saying.  I've had another look at the style guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html) and, yes I may have gone overboard with the module files.  But will I need these module files in order to set up routing (my main question)?

Comment: No, you don't need a module file for each component in order to set up routing: see the example of crisis module in the link I give above.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you need lazy loading or not.

If not: it should be in one file.

If you need it:

Main routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'eager', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'eager', component: EagerComponent },
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];
```

And routing of  lazy loaded component:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LazyComponent } from './lazy.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LazyComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

For more information check this tutorial:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html